# List Processing in Prolog and Scheme

Tags: list, prolog, scheme

I was trying to pick up a language between prolog and Scheme. I understand both uses list as the only data structure. So, my question is in terms of list processing capabilities which of these two languages is more powerful or how their list processing differ from each other.

Comment: More than the "list processing capabilities" what you have to consider is that they're using two completely different programming paradigms, Prolog uses logic programming and Scheme is, in essence (but not restricted to), a functional programming language. If it's just list processing, Scheme is a great choice and has very mature libraries in the form of SRFIs.

Comment: Thanks but considering just list Processing, in what ways Scheme is better. I mean are there some features which are there in Scheme and not in Prolog in terms of list processing only?

Comment: In Scheme there are _tons_ of list-processing functions (higher-order procedures), libraries, etc. all designed for manipulating lists, dive into the documentation of your interpreter, you'll see what I mean

Comment: In Prolog we have recursive data structures (terms), lists are just a very specific kind of terms, with dedicated 'syntax sugar'. The most important data in Prolog are *logical variables*. In a sense, lists are mostly used to *serialize* the proof.

Comment: Pick Prolog and forget about the rest. Its list processing abilities are at least as advanced as those of other languages, and Prolog also supports infix operators that make Prolog code easier to read than that of most other homoiconic languages.

Comment: "list as the only data structure"  While the list is an important and common data structure, it's not the only data stucture in these languages.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor    I did not mean to say that list is the only data structure. I meant I will primarily be using these languages for list processing.